# How can I use glut primitives with glfw3?

Tags: opengl, glut, glfw

I'm learning about OpenGL graphics and the demonstrator has given us glut; however, it doesn't satisfy the needs of the project.

So, I want to move on to glfw3 but am having an issue with the primitives like, `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, `GL_LINE_LOOP`, etc.

How can I use the primitives to draw polygons and lines using glfw3?

Comment: What kind of issues do you have? Explain in more detail and show us an example of your problem.

Comment: I'm given an error message that gives output 'the program was unable to start correctly', the program is a chess board squares and white lines I tried to follow the glfw.org guide :).

Comment: GLUT provides font and geometric object rendering as well as a menu system which GLFW does not provide, while GLFW lets you address specific monitors in a multi-monitor setup which GLUT does not. GLFW also has a more sophisticated input handling scheme. What combination of capabilities are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for combining the glfw set mouse position function with glut primitive drawing.

Comment: Have you tried doing everything in glut and using glutWarpPointer to set your cursor position?